# Decode Json Data in Kotlin and pass it in Socket emit event

Tags: android, socket.io

I want to decode JSON data

from :->

**{"receiver_id":"193","signal_data":{},"sender_id":"192","call_to":"null"}**

to like this:->

**{receiver_id:193,signal_data:{},sender_id:192,call_to:null}**

how can I do this in android does anybody know?

I tried JsonParser. but it doesn't work